# USB Linux Install w/ LUKS Encryption: Will Suspend to RAM Work?

Tags: encryption, usb-flash-drive, debian-squeeze, luks

I installed Debian Squeeze on a 8GB flash drive. So far, it is stock Squeeze (opted for Laptop and Standard System in Expert Mode install). Before I go nuts, I am trying to run a stripped down distro with some features, mainly for use on my underpowered EeePC 700 Surf 2G (the glorious original). It might need to work other places, but that is not my concern right now.

What I do want to know is this: if I configure suspend to RAM (I know there are a few options, but [TuxOnIce seems feature-rich and appealing](http://wiki.tuxonice.net/EncryptedSwapAndRoot). So, does anyone do this with an externally attached USB key on a laptop or desktop?

Comment: Suspend to RAM generally does not interfere with disk encryption, but leaves the disk unlocked for anyone to access. ToI usually refers to Suspend to Disk, though, which *will* interfere with encryption. This is solved with an initramfs, probably provided by Debian.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Coming up from hibername (suspend to disk), requires you to do a full cold boot. At some point in initrd, I believe, it will check for a hibernation image to restore. If one isn't found or is incompatible, it will continue boot.

So, it should work presuming you can boot off that device and configure TuxOnIce (or whatever the used method is, I can't remember) to correctly make and restore the image.

I've used hibernate in Debian squeezy systems on HDD and SSD, and it Just Works. I never tried to boot from anything off USB, though. I would suggest trying it and reporting back whether it worked :)